# AsyncTask context SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm making an application that get data from `webservice`, insert it into a database and show the data into a `tablelayout`.

So what I want to do is that in a X lapse of time, REFRESH the table with the content of `webservice`.

I can do that with the `onResume` method, but it isn't what I want.

I was reading about `asynctask`, so the task of using `webservice` and inserting data into sqlite could be in a second thread.

In the method `doInBackground` I start the `webservice` and insert information into a sqlite, and in the `onPostExecute` I put the information dynamically into a table.

My problem is that, when I initialize the database to read it, I put:

```
 UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh = new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBIncidentes", null, 1);
```

and in THIS, there is a context problem.

This happened too in the part of refreshing data into the table (in onPostExecute), because all the time I put THIS like creating a textview, there is a context problem.

I basically know about context, I read that I have to create a constructor of the `asynctask` class and initialize a context, and I can change THIS for the context of the constructor.

I'm a bit lost in this part, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `this` refers to your ASyncTask and not your Activity. You need to use `ActivityName.this` instead.